# Como extraer datos de textbox y datagriedview a una tabla de oracle?

Tags: c#, oracle-11g

Junto con saludar, tengo unas dudas respecto a una tarea que estoy realizando con Oracle.Dataccess.Client:

mi clase conexion esta como publica

//Clase Conexion
OracleConnection cnn = new OracleConnection("DATA SOURCE=xxx;PASSWORD=xxxxx;USER ID=FERME");

Tengo que crear una boleta, tomando todos los textbox del grupo (Detalles Boleta) y ademas los datos del datagridview con el boton agregar boleta.

[image: Vista Boletas]

La tabla a la que debe caer es esta:
[image: Tabla Boletas]

Hasta ahora tengo asi el metodo pero me esta lanzando error
[image: Error]

Este es el codigo de error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo bien.. por formatos de la grilla te referis a como recorrer y sacar los gratos de la grilla?

Comment: Si a recorrer lo que tiene mas que nada el formulario completo (grilla + textbox que estan arriba) y con todos esos datos crear en a BD una boleta

Comment: pero los textbox ya los estas pasando.. revisa la propiedad rows de la grilla...

Comment: Los textbox (id_producto, cantidad y nombre) los estoy pasando a la grilla, para luego con el boton Agregar boleta, se agreguen los textboxrestantes (nro_boleta, rut, dv, vendedor, etc) + los datos que estan en la grilla. Ahora si tu crees que me estoy complicando mucho, y existe otra manera seria genial, te leo atento.

Comment: ese error es otra cosa totalmente diferente y ya esta contestado en el sitio... y supongo que la grilla va a parar a otra tabla no?

Comment: Como lo dije, los datos de la grilla mas los textbox del grupo superior, van a parar a la tabla Boleta de mi base de datos.

Comment: los datos de los productos no pueden ir nunca a la misma tabla que tiene la cabecera.. si no, vas a repetir los datos de cabecera por cada producto... montones de veces..

Comment: mmm entonces como podria plantear un sistema de boleta por productos? tipo drag and drop

Comment: los productos van en otra tabla.. tu base de datos debe estar normalizada.. lo que estas haciendo en tu codigo es correcto.. lo que estas haciendo en tu db no parece.. salvo que ese SP guarde los datos en otra tabla.. y reciba los datos de otra manera.. igual, primero soluciona el error que te salio

Comment: gracias por lo del error, intentare ver cual es la excepcion nula